# Angular setting img[src] to null even thought it has value

Tags: angular

I have created a pair of directive, one to

HTML

```html
<div>
    <h3>Both</h3>
    <img
        sGetSrc="//via.placeholder.com/120x60?text=Good"
        sFallback="//via.placeholder.com/120x60?text=Fallback"
    >
</div>
```

GetSrcDirective [sGetSrc]

```ts
export class GetSrcDirective {
    @HostBinding('src') @Input('sGetSrc') image!: string;
}
```

FallbackDirective[sFallback]

```ts
export class FallbackDirective {
    @HostBinding('class.no-image') hasError = false;

    private originalSrc!: string;
    @Input('src') set src(value: string) {
        if (!value) { return; }
        if (value == this.originalSrc) { return; }

        this.hasError = false;
        this.originalSrc = value;
    }
    @Input() sFallback!: string;

    @HostBinding('src') get currentSrc(): string {
        if (this.hasError) {
            return this.sFallback;
        } else {
            return this.originalSrc;
        }
    }

    @HostListener('error')
    failure() {
        this.hasError = true;
    }
}
```

From this code, I expected that it would set `src` to some value from GetSrcDirective directive, then that the FallbackDirective should change img[src] in the event of an error.

But now somehow the src get set to null, to be exact I have done some debugging and it does these things in order as fallow, thus resulting in setting `src` to null:

- Build AppComponent
- Create GetSrcDirective

  - Set `sGetSrc` to `image`
  - Set image `src` to `image`
- Create FallbackDirective

  - Set invoke `Input('src')` to `image`
  - Set image `src` to `value`
- Finish rest
- Now debug cycle runs
- Set `sGetSrc` to **`null`**
- Set img src to `null`
- loading image...
- img[src=null] call error
- FallbackDirective reacts and update img[src] to fallback image

Did I miss any behaviour, or is this angular error?

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pvqy4g

Comment: What's the behavior you're expecting?

Comment: @FedericoGalfione have a look, I have edited question (just after code)

Comment: Why do you need the `GetSrcDirective`? You can just bind to src and achieve the same. Then you don't have a problem with the directives clashing. This is very tricky what you are doing manipulating the src property from two directives.

Comment: @AlesD I am separating concerns my src getter is much more complicated, yet synchronous thus I just made the example that much more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have spoken to the Angular team and they very kindly responded with:

> In general I don't believe this code is working how you expect it to. In Angular, one directive cannot set the input to another - if an element has two directives and one of them has a `@HostBinding('[src]')` for example, this will not result in the other directive's `@Input('src')` being updated. The only thing that can update an `@Input` is a binding expression in a template.

With that, I have realised that the simple way to fix it is just to have directives communicate with each other.

GetSrcDirective [sGetSrc]

```
export class GetSrcDirective {
    @HostBinding('src') srcBinding!: string;
    @Input('sGetSrc') set image(source: string) {
        this.srcBinding = source
        if (this.fallbackDirective) {
            this.fallbackDirective.setSource(source);
        }
    }

    constructor(
        @Host() @Optional() fallbackDirective: FallbackDirective,
    ) { }

}
```

FallbackDirective[sFallback]

```
export class FallbackDirective {
    @HostBinding('class.no-image') hasError = false;

    private originalSrc!: string;
    @Input('src') set src(value: string) {
        if (!value) { return; }
        this.setSource(value);
    }
    @Input() sFallback!: string;

    @HostBinding('src') get currentSrc(): string {
        if (this.hasError) {
            return this.sFallback;
        } else {
            return this.originalSrc;
        }
    }

    setSource(source: string) {
        if (value == this.originalSrc) { return; }

        this.hasError = false;
        this.originalSrc = value;
    }

    @HostListener('error')
    failure() {
        this.hasError = true;
    }
}
```

The important part is `@Host() @Optional() fallbackDirective: FallbackDirective` it says, get `FallbackDirective` that is on the same element, if it exists. Then if we have it we update it directly, thus working around the problem. This is also the way Angular want us to do it.